# Get id's div with dynamic generation of divs

Tags: javascript, ajax

Let's say I have :

```
<div id="form">
    <div id="form_field1_0">
        <div id="form_field1_0_att1"></div>
        <div id="form_field1_0_att2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="form_field1_1">
        <div id="form_field1_1_att1"></div>
        <div id="form_field1_1_att2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="form_field1_0">
        <div id="form_field1_2_att1"></div>
        <div id="form_field1_2_att2"></div>
    </div>
    //...
</div>
```

And I have a Javascript function which add as many `#form_field1_n` as the user wants.

And now, I want a `change()` call for each `#form_field1_`n`_att1`.

How would you do that ?

Here is the Javascript which add divs (with my id's div):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $container = $('div#mybundle_serveur_typesDetails');
        var $addLink = $('<a href="#" id="add_type" class="">Ajouter un type</a>');
        $container.append($addLink);
        $addLink.click(function(e) {
            addSource($container);
            e.preventDefault(); // évite qu'un # apparaisse dans l'URL
            return false;
        });

        var index = $container.find(':input').length;

        if (index == 0) {
            addSource($container);
        } else {
            $container.children('div').each(function() {
                addDeleteLink($(this));
            });
        }

        function addSource($container) {
            var $prototype = $($container.attr('data-prototype').replace(/__name__label__/g, 'type n°' + (index+1))
                .replace(/__name__/g, index));

            addDeleteLink($prototype);

            $container.append($prototype);
            index++;
        }

        function addDeleteLink($prototype) {
            $deleteLink = $('<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Supprimer</a>');

            $prototype.append($deleteLink);

            $deleteLink.click(function(e) {
                $prototype.remove();
                e.preventDefault(); // évite qu'un # apparaisse dans l'URL
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried to do that in my Javascript with : 
                $prototype.className = "ok_test";
but nothing is happening in the html...

Answer (score 0):

You can match your elements with following pattern:

```
$('[id^="form_field1_"]')
```

You can also set the same a class for those elements and match them i.e. using

```
$('.form_field1_class')
```

...or even store the IDs in some array and reffer to them.

But I'll go with the one of the first two solutions.

Comment: Thanks ! And if the id is something like this : form_field1_n_field with n a number how would you do with the pattern ?

Answer (score 0):

If you give then all a class e.g.

```
<div id="form_field1_2_att1" class="att1"></div>
```

Then you can use delegated event handling in jQuery to assign an event handler to them all, regardless of how many get created. Bear in mind though that a `<div>` does not have a "change" event, so for an example I've used "click" instead:

```
$(document).on("click", ".att1", function(event) {
   alert($(this).attr("id")); //this line is just as a test
});
```